# How to fetch a dicom element from a .dcm file using pydicom if an element is in square brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dicom, pydicom

I am trying to extract a dicom file using pydicom library.

```
    filename="C:\\Users\\1016086\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\dicomeSample.dcm'
    dataset = pydicom.dcmread(filename)
```

So, I have to get the value of below element
`(0011, 1004) [Acquisition Type]                  CS: 'SE'`

But I couldn't get the value of 'Acquisition Type' since it is in square brackets.

I have tried `dataset.get(Acquisition Type)` and `dataset.get_item(Acquisition Type)`
But it is not showing error in python IDE since it has space in between the key `'Acquisition Type'`

Comment: `get_item` method cannot get strings, only pairs of numbers. Try to use `get`.

Comment: @Zefick I have used dataset.get(Acquisition Type) but the space in between the two word shows error. Also tried with dataset.get("Acquisition Type"). It is also showing the error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Items with square brackets are private tags, not dicom keywords, and pydicom does not accept those as they are not necessarily unique. They are displayed only as a convenience.

You have to access those by the tag number, e.g.
ds[(0x0011, 0x1004)].value

Edited: added '0x' in front of hex numbers in tag

Answer (score 0):

It works without space.
Just use dataset.AcquisitionType without space.

```
import os
import pydicom
from pydicom.data import get_testdata_files

filename="C:\\Users\\1016086\\PycharmProjects\\untitled\\dicomeSample.dcm"
dataset = pydicom.dcmread(filename)
print(dataset.AcquisitionType)
```

Comment: I am getting the error as : AttributeError("'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'AcquisitionType'",))

Comment: use dataset.[AcquisitionType] and tell me the output please

Comment: dataset.[AcquisitionType] cannot compile, syntax error